Как правильно подать запрос к mysql по списку значений Primart Key
Всем добра, форумчане!
Суть задачи такова: есть массив значений ключа таблица
Нужно выгрузить данные из таблицы по этим ключам. Работаю через PHP
Как правильно подавать запрос? Разделить пары ключ-значение оператором OR:
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE key=1 OR key=2 OR key=3...
Или
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE key IN (1, 2,3,4...);  #до 1000 ключей

Или в цикле подставлять в подготовленный запрос значения ключа?
$query = '
    SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE key=?
';

/*  ...
    Инициализация подготовленного запроса
*/

foreach (keys as key) {
    stmt -> execute();
}


Зависит от количества значений в списке. Если 3-4, то через OR, если 10-20, то WHERE IN, иначе слить во временную таблицу и INNER JOIN. А цикл - это заведомо медленно... Кстати, а что именно оптимизируется? Скорость, ресурсы, простота кода, прочее?

Это бэкэнд) Тут главное чтобы ресурсов меньше ело. А ключи - это результаты поиска. Их может быть непредсказуемое количество вплоть до 1000

ГДЕ ИМЕННО меньше ресурсов ело?

Я новичек в Mysql, поэтому и ищу правильное решение. Суть данного запроса - фильтрация и сортировка по данным из таблицы

Вероятнее всего мне нужно минимизировать количество обращений к БД, в то же время, поиск по ключам внутри массива может занимать дольше времени

Суть моего обращения в том, что постоянное сравнение  в каждой итерации по длинному условию с OR или WHERE IN может увеличить нагрузку на БД, если это конечно же не оптимизированно разработчиками mysql

...ключи - это результаты поиска... это, очевидно, результат какого-то запроса, а не пользовательского ввода? Тогда вам ничего не мешает сделать ...FROM table JOIN (SELECT...<текст вашего запроса на поиск>...) ON <связь по ключу>

Ну очевидно же, что в цикле будет дольше всего. А IN и OR это одно и то же. Но как правильно уже написали ПРАВИЛЬНОЕ решение это не получать ключи из одного запроса и подставлять в другой, а сразу делать одним запросом, через JOIN
